# How to find the occupancy each hour?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, aggregate

I'm trying to show how many people are in the gym in any given time.

I've been provided the sign-in data and would like to display the occupancy for each hour like so:

```
Date/Time | Occupants
1/1/2018 7:00AM | 4
1/1/2018 8:00AM | 12
1/1/2018 9:00AM | 16
1/1/2018 10:00AM | 13
1/1/2018 11:00AM | 11
```

The sign-in info is provided like this: (PS I'm assuming people spend roughly 1.5 hrs there for now, there are roughly 100,000 rows.)

```
Sign In | Sign Out
1/1/18 9:00 AM  | 1/1/18 10:30 AM
1/1/18 10:16 AM | 1/1/18 11:46 AM
1/1/18 10:18 AM | 1/1/18 11:48 AM
1/1/18 10:29 AM | 1/1/18 11:59 AM
1/1/18 10:30 AM | 1/1/18 12:00 PM
1/1/18 10:33 AM | 1/1/18 12:03 PM
1/1/18 11:27 AM | 1/1/18 12:57 PM
1/1/18 11:36 AM | 1/1/18 1:06 PM
1/1/18 11:37 AM | 1/1/18 1:07 PM
1/1/18 11:51 AM | 1/1/18 1:21 PM
1/1/18 11:52 AM | 1/1/18 1:22 PM
```

What would be a good way to aggregate this data into each hour? I'd appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have to assume, people spend 1.5 hr when you do have `Sign Out` info? And if you do by the assumption, then you do not need `Sign Out` column.

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified: I added the Sign-Out column just to show on here, the data doesn't actually contain it.

Comment: okay, checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for help with the aggregation?

You can use groupby, with a count.

```
In = df['Sign In'].groupby([df['Sign In'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%B %d, %Y, %H'))]).count()
Out = df['Sign In'].groupby([df['Sign Out'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%B %d, %Y, %H'))]).count()

Sign In
January 01, 2018, 09    1
January 01, 2018, 10    5
January 01, 2018, 11    5
Name: Sign In, dtype: int64
Sign Out
January 01, 2018, 10    1
January 01, 2018, 11    3
January 01, 2018, 12    3
January 01, 2018, 13    4
Name: Sign In, dtype: int64
```

You can then work from here to rename columns, apply logic (ie this is just the current delta) and do a merge to join the frames together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply add how many people came at a `Sign In` time (In our case, 1). Then [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) it with `1.5H`.

```
df['people'] = 1
df.set_index(['Sign In']).resample('1.5H').count()
```

Output:

```
                    people
Sign In 
2018-01-01 09:00:00 4
2018-01-01 10:30:00 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my shot

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# convert to the right type
data['Sign In ']= data['Sign In '].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p '))

data[' Sign Out']= data[' Sign Out'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, ' %d/%m/%y %I:%M %p'))

# save in and Out 
signin= pd.to_datetime(data['Sign In '])
signout= pd.to_datetime(data[' Sign Out'])

# in groupby you could add [signin.dt.date, signin.dt.hour] if necessary
In = data.groupby([signin.dt.hour]).count().drop(' Sign Out', axis=1)  

Out= data.groupby([signout.dt.hour]).count().drop('Sign In ', axis=1) 

In.index.rename('time', inplace=True)
Out.index.rename('time', inplace=True)

# concatenate in data 
data = pd.concat([In, Out], axis=1).fillna(0)
data['occupancy'] = (data['Sign In '] - data[' Sign Out']).cumsum()
```

## Output

```
print(data) 

      Sign In    Sign Out  occupancy
time                                
9          1.0        0.0        1.0
10         5.0        1.0        5.0
11         5.0        3.0        7.0
12         0.0        3.0        4.0
13         0.0        4.0        0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution works also on data with presence periods other than 1.5 hour,
but dates must be from a **single** day (according to how you assembled
your sample data).

I read your data as *fixed width fields* with conversion to *datetime*:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(txt), colspecs=[(0, 15), (18, 33)],
    names=['Sign In', 'Sign Out'], parse_dates=[0, 1])
```

so from the very beginning I have proper data types (no need for extra calls
of *pd.to_datetime*).

The first preparatory step is to create an *IntervalIndex*:

```
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['Sign In'], df['Sign Out'], closed='left')
```

The next step is to create *hrs* - a list of full hours:

```
hrs = pd.date_range(df['Sign In'].min(),
    df['Sign Out'].max() + pd.Timedelta('1H'), freq='H')
```

Note that I added 1 extra hour to the *max* value, in order to have the
"final" hour, after everybody came out.
Something like the last hour with *0* occupancy, as *CHAMI* did. 
If you don't need it, just delete this extra hour.

But we need a *Series* with both index and values set to these hours, so
I created also *hours*:

```
hours = pd.Series(hrs, index=hrs)
```

And having these data, the actual computation can be performed in
a **single** instruction:

```
occupancy = hours.apply(lambda hr: np.count_nonzero(
    intervals.map(lambda it: hr in it)))
```

The result is:

```
2018-01-01 09:00:00    1
2018-01-01 10:00:00    1
2018-01-01 11:00:00    5
2018-01-01 12:00:00    6
2018-01-01 13:00:00    4
2018-01-01 14:00:00    0
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

It is worth to do some comparison with other answers:

- The answer by *CHAMI* has *float* type of data (it shoud be *int*).
- *CHAMI* solution shows occupancy at 10:00 as **5**, whereas at this
  time actually only **1** person was present. Clients No 2 thru 6
  signed in later (**after** 10:00).
- Results for 10:00 and subsequent hours in his solution are "shifted"
  by 1 hour.
- It is a bad habbit to include leading / trailing spaces in column names
  (as *CHAMI* did).
- *krewsider* actually shows only **aggregation of sign in / out events**,
  but not occupancy.
- *harvpan* took **1.5** hours step (why?). Another detail is that he
  shows occupancy at *9:00* as **4** (why?) and his result is by far
  incomplete.

Note also such a difference, that *CHAMI* showed **7** occupancy at *11:00*
(actually at *12:00*), but I showed **6**.
The reason is that I assumed that if person No 5 left sharp at *12:00*,
so at this time he was already **absent**.

If you want to treat such a person as still present, change the *closed*
attribute of the *IntervalIndex* to *'both'* and for your data the result
at *12:00* will be **7**.